# Remove base object in Json output in Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

We need to remove the base List object (equipmentMetrics) in this kind of return:

```
{
"equipmentMetrics": [{
    "id": "BOSS|C5E02126",
    "reportedHours": "499.9998",
    "reportingDate": "2012-10-10"
}, {
    "id": "BOSS|C5E02126",
    "reportedHours": "499.9998",
    "reportingDate": "2012-11-10"
}]
```

}

We are using Jersey and this object:

```
     @XmlRootElement(name = "equipmentMetrics")
    public class EquipmentMetricsResponse {
        private String id;
...}
```

And this endpoint:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("")
public List<EquipmentMetricsResponse> postV1Default(EquipmentMetricsRequest theRequest) {...}
```

I believe we want the response to look like this.  We just want to take out the:

> "equipmentMetrics":

So I believe we want this:

```
[{
        "id": "BOSS|C5E02126",
        "reportedHours": "499.9998",
        "reportingDate": "2012-10-10"
    }, {
        "id": "BOSS|C5E02126",
        "reportedHours": "499.9998",
        "reportingDate": "2012-11-10"
    }]
```

Any help?

Comment: What you want the JSON response to look like is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: I added a bit of clarification.  We just want to send the list with no base object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `com.google.gson.Gson` library.

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("")
public String postV1Default(EquipmentMetricsRequest theRequest) {
   List<EquipmentMetricsResponse> retVal ...
   ...  
   return new Gson().toJson(retVal);  
}
```

returned JSON is

```
   [{
        "id": "BOSS|C5E02126",
        "reportedHours": "499.9998",
        "reportingDate": "2012-10-10"
    }, {
        "id": "BOSS|C5E02126",
        "reportedHours": "499.9998",
        "reportingDate": "2012-11-10"
    }]
```